# Rotate one duplicated screen without rotating the other Windows 8

Tags: windows, display

I need to duplicate my desktop to show a video on two screens however the second one is rotated at an angle of 90 degrees.

I'm aware when you duplicate the screen any rotations are applied to both screens is there a way for this not to happen.

I've tried writing some C++ to change it however as soon as I apply the rotation to the second screen it forces the settings for the first screen to change as well. I'm considering write a program to give me the functionality I need however I need this today or tomorrow at the latest so there isn't really much time.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to rotate one screen and not the other while in duplicate mode. If you make it so that one monitor is an extended screen it will rotate by itself.

Alternatively your videoplayer may have the option to rotate the screen 90°. I know for example that both VLC media player and Media Player Classic from the k-lite codec pack can do this. Note that rotating the video itself will rotate it at both screens too. Thats just how duplicate works.

Comment: I feared as much, looks like the easiest option will be to just use two computers, one for pc display one for projector display :(

Comment: or not rotate the 2nd screen, or rotate the first one too.

Comment: No I need one rotated and one not, the first feed is for the user the second screen is mounted sidewards (can't change that) for an audience, so one needs to be rotated and the other not

Answer (score 1):

I'm years late to the party, but hopefully for others looking for this info it'll still be of use.

Achieving this in Windows 10 (might work on Windows 8.1 also, don't know) is easy, but not obvious.

First, extend your desktop to the monitor you wish to adjust.
Second, set the orientation you want on that monitor.
Third, change the 'extend' mode to 'duplicate' instead.

Now, your image will be properly oriented on the other display.

Comment: Confirmed! Works in win10

Comment: Doesn't work for me on win 10 - i feel like a fool fighting with it for hours... :( I'm not an Apple fanboy but there it took 30sec - set separate orientation for each screen and add mirror check.
Unfortunately I need to achieve it on Win 10...

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. You can extend it in the correct rotation, but not duplicate AND have it in the correct rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue. Running Windows 11. Connected a Gaomon drawing tablet screen. For the life of me Windows would not stop flipping the drawing tablet screen when I duplicated 1 to 2. After frustratingly expressing the simple question of "Why?!" for the 33rd time in a loop back direction to myself, I opened the graphics card NVIDIA Control Panel and when I duplicated it there it was no problem. Windows now shows it duplicated and orientation is what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

## Have two screens and want one horizontal and one vertical.

when you have extended(meaning two)screen, It IS POSSIBLE to have  one landscape/horizontal and one portrait/vertical. I just did that.
1) Right click mouse button while cursor is on the background screen of your PC.
2) From drop down select "Screen Resolution" the menu may be different based on Windows version.
3) You will get screen that show tile "Change the appearance of your displays", you will see two rectangle labeled 1 and 2 representing the two  monitors.
4) Select the display rectangle labeled 1 or 2, which ever one you want rotated.
5)look at the screen details there is one titles ORIENTATION, using the drop down menu choose Landscape or Portrait.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP notes his screens are Duplicate, while your answer admits it is only for Extended mode.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.